# Xming Alternative for ubuntu

Tags: xorg, remote-desktop, remote, x11-forwarding

I have a ubuntu machine that can be accessed remotely using putty. I run xming in the windows and Enabled X11 forwarding in putty. So if i start wireshark in the putty, i get the display in my windows. If I need to do the same thing from ubuntu, what should be installed. That is. From one ubuntu pc I am doing ssh to the remote machine. what software should be installed so that i can see the ui(if i start wireshark in the remote pc in the ssh).

Thanks & Regards,
JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing.

You can install putty if you like, but there is a command line ssh client installed by default. There is no need for another X Server (that is what xming is).

The default command to start a ssh session with X fordwarding enabled is:

```
ssh -X target.machine.address
```

Comment: Yeah.. I am able to do ssh to the remote machine. But If i start wireshark in the remote machine, I get this error "(wireshark:12931): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0.0"

Comment: I have made an edit to the answer, if it doesn't help please add: How are you connecting?. Using putty or the default ssh cliente?. Are you using any command line switchs?. Have you changed something in putty config?